# Replace a row in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

So i have a csv file:

```
Today</span><span class='invisible'>3:00 p.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today</span><span class='invisible'>1:52 p.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today</span><span class='invisible'>12:50 p.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today</span><span class='invisible'>11:42 a.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today</span><span class='invisible'>9:56 a.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 25, 2013
```

and I need to replace all the rows that start with `Today` and replace it with the date that is currently in the line. So far I've been running a for-loop:

```
rownumber=$(wc -l < DateStamp.csv)
for ((i=1; i<=$rownumber; i++))
do
    s1=$(awk -v "row=$i" -F'@' 'NR == row { print $1 }' DateStamp.csv)
    if [[ "$s1" =~ 'Today' ]]
        then
            year=$(date +'%Y')
            text=$(awk -v "row=$i" -F'@' 'NR == row { print $1 }' DateStamp.csv | grep -o -P "(?<=m\. ).*(?<=$year)")
                            __SOME COMMAND__
        else
            break
    fi
done
```

I want my output to be this:

```
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 25, 2013
```

Is there a line which I can replace with **SOME COMMAND** that will replace the row I am in with my variable `text`? Maybe a `sed` or `awk` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the presence of `a.m.` or `p.m.` in front of the date is guaranteed, do you really need to parse and extract the date from the `Today` lines? The following may suffice

```
sed 's/.*[ap]\.m\.\s\+\(.*\)$/\1/' DateStamp.csv
```

This uses a capture group `\(.*\)` to collect the portion after `a.m` or `p.m.` and replaces the entire input line with the contents of this capture group. [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) just passes through the original line otherwise

Comment: alright I get the gist of it, I'm going to play around with sed to try to understand it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easy with `awk`

```
awk '/^Today/ {$0=$4 FS $5 FS $6}1' DateStamp.csv
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 29, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 27, 2013
Nov. 25, 2013
```

If line starts with `Today`, set line equal to field 4,5 and 6. Then print everything out.

Comment: Jotne, your awk answers are always insightful, +1!