# How to grep HH:MM for the first occurance for each line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a csv file like so:

```
Today's event is at 12:00 p.m. Today, which is 12:00 p.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today's event is at 05:00 a.m. Today, which is 05:00 a.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Today's event is at 07:00 p.m. Today, which is 07:00 p.m. Nov. 29, 2013
Tomorrow's event is at 06:00 a.m.
Tomorrow's event is at 04:00 p.m.
```

I wanna grep the first occurrences of time in each line. 
I've tried:
`grep -E -o ".{0,2}:.{0,6}"` but this gives me all the occurrences of time and gives me this:

```
12:00 p.m.
12:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
05:00 a.m.
07:00 a.m.
07:00 a.m.
06:00 a.m.
04:00 p.m.
```

and I just need the first occurrence so my output will be this:

```
12:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
07:00 a.m.
06:00 a.m.
04:00 p.m.
```

is there a way with grep?

Comment: Are both times on one line the same?

Comment: for the first three lines they are, that's why `grep -E -o ".{0,2}:.{0,6}"` gives me eight occurrences but i just need five of the first occurrences in each line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

process one line each time:

```
while read L; do grep -E -o "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (p|a)\.m\." <<< $L|head -1; done < cvs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
[ ~]$ egrep -o "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\ *(p\.m|a\.m)\." test.txt|sort -u
04:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
06:00 a.m.
07:00 p.m.
12:00 p.m.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cut off all bytes after, e.g., 40:

```
cat csvfile.csv | cut -b 1-40 | grep -E -o ".{0,2}:.{0,6}"
```

This ensures `grep` only searches for dates in the first 40 bytes of each line.

Answer (score 0):

one [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) option

```
sed 's/.*\(.\{2\}:.\{0,6\}\).*$/\1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close to a question you already asked here:
[Replace a row in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293922/replace-a-row-in-a-csv-file/20294133?noredirect=1#comment30282756_20294133)
So by modify my answer, you get:

```
awk '/^Today|^Tomorrow/ {$0=$5 FS $6} $0!=f; {f=$0}' file
12:00 p.m.
05:00 a.m.
07:00 p.m.
06:00 a.m.
04:00 p.m.
```

This looks if line is starting with `Today` or `Tomorrow`, then test if its printed before, if not print it.

PS you are asking for `grep`, but as you accepting an answer with `while` `grep` and `head`, an single `awk` should do to.